# RC first-grade circuit with op. amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis

I tried to calculate the voltage \$v_u\$ in this RC circuit, but I got stuck when it comes to calculate \$v_u(\infty)\$ and \$\tau\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffnjNg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then: \$v_u(t)=[v_u(0)-v_u(\infty)]e^\frac{-t}{\tau}+v_u(\infty)\$

First off, I notice that \$v_u(t)=-v_c(t)\$.

Then I calculate \$v_u(0)\$,\$v_u(\infty)\$ and \$\tau\$.

**First step: \$v_u(0)\$**

The circuit become the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DAK0.png)</sup>

Here the current \$i=i_1+i_2=0 \implies v_c(0)=0 => v_u(0)=0\$.

**Second step: \$v_u(\infty)\$**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb9uat.png)</sup>

Now \$R_g\$ is in series with \$R\$, so \$v_c=E\frac{R}{R+R_g} => v_u=-E\frac{R}{R+R_g}\$.

Is this correct? My books gives \$v_u(\infty)=-E\frac{R}{R_g}\$.

**Third step: \$\tau\$**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbw4iS.png)</sup>

Since \$\tau=R_{eq}C\$, I have to calculate \$R_{eq}=\frac{v_c}{i_R}\$.

Let's calculate \$i_R\$: \$i_R=i+i_1+i_2=i+i_1=i+i_3+i_4=i+i_4\$

Now how much is \$i_4\$? The solution says that \$i_R=i\$. So, why is \$i_4=0\$?

Comment: in the second step the resistors do not form a voltage divider.  The opamp input is a virtual ground.  Try again with the '-' terminal of the opamp at ground.

Comment: in the third step i4 is 0 because it is the ground current of the opamp and not germane to your signal processing problem.

Comment: Thank you crgrace. I undertand the error in the 2nd step. Just a question: why in the 3d step i4 doesn't concern my problem?

Comment: the only "signal" terminals of your opamp are the + and - inputs and the output.  i_4 is the current *used* by the opamp.  It could be very low if you have a low-power opamp, or it could be extremely high if you used a very old opamp or something.  The point is the relation between the signals wouldn't change.  Can you imagine if using a lower power opamp changed everyone's circuits?   There would be chaos!